# Alternatives to JsonOutputFormatter in ASP.NET Core 3.1 at Controller Level

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a custom filter attribute adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56127866/1845714) currently implemented for .NET Core 2.2 that I would like to adapt to 3.1. It references Newtonsoft.JSON and I would prefer to keep it that way for compatibility reasons.

The code follows:

```
public class AllPropertiesAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext ctx)
    {
        if (!(ctx.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)) return;

        var serializer = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include };
        serializer.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());

        var formatter = new JsonOutputFormatter(serializer, 
                        ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ArrayPool<char>>());

        objectResult.Formatters.Add(formatter);
    }
}
```

`JsonOutputFormatter` is only supported up to .net core 2.2, [according to the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.jsonoutputformatter?view=aspnetcore-2.2); how should I proceed to keep the same behavior under 3.1?

Comment: @MikeZboray thanks for the reply - my attempt at switching to the native formatter came to a stop when I learned that it behaved in a different way, ignoring properties from derived types when emitting JSON responses; this being the reason why I'm sticking with Newtonsoft.JSON, at least for the time being. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308763/derived-types-properties-missing-in-json-response-from-asp-net-core-api

Comment: Yes, I missed that you wanted to stay with newtonsoft for compatibility reasons. I think the Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package is where you want to look. Specifically, NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter seems to be the equivalent output formatter.

Comment: @MikeZboray I can't believe I missed that one - tried it and it worked flawlessly with some small changes. Would you post an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The equivalent of the old JsonOutputFormatter is NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package. It has one minor change, where it will accept an MvcOptions in the constructor as well:

```
    public NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter(
        JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings,
        ArrayPool<char> charPool,
        MvcOptions mvcOptions)
```

This is only really affects the behavior via the [SuppressOutputFormatterBuffering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.suppressoutputformatterbuffering?view=aspnetcore-3.1) option. You might be able to resolve it from the RequestServices or you can just create a new one on the fly.

Comment: It's now depreciated, you need to add an additional parameter of `MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions? jsonOptions` at the end per [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.newtonsoftjsonoutputformatter.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-formatters-newtonsoftjsonoutputformatter-ctor(newtonsoft-json-jsonserializersettings-system-buffers-arraypool((system-char))-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-mvcoptions-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-mvcnewtonsoftjsonoptions))

Answer (score 4):

The migration guide for Net Core 2.2 -> 3.0 has this information

[Migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support)

The jist, you can use it you just have to manually add the package since its no longer included by default

- Add a package reference to AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
- Add the following to your Startup.ConfigureServices method

  ```
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson();
  ```
- Configure

Comment: Thanks Josh, that's quite close to that I have at initialization. My question have a slightly different focus - I'd like to have a different serialization behavior at controller level (i.e. a method that handles response serialization in a different way.) I still appreciate the time you took to answer though.

Answer (score 4):

.Net Core 3 brings with it [its own JSON capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to) and does not include Json.Net anymore by default.

As an alternative, if this is possible, you can use the native [SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.systemtextjsonoutputformatter?view=aspnetcore-3.1) instead of including another package.

```s-sharp
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;

public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext ctx)
{
    if (!(ctx.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)) return;

    var serializer = new JsonSerializerOptions { IgnoreNullValues = false };
    serializer.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());

    var formatter = new SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter(serializer);

    objectResult.Formatters.Add(formatter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, SanBen. I've ultimately decided to stick with NewtonsoftJson because of a design choice for JsonOutputFormatter - namely, it ignores properties from derived types.