# How can I return a List<BaseClass> with Children properties?

Tags: c#, json, abp

How can I return a list of Base class objects with its sub types properties from a .NET 5 controller.

```
public class StepBaseDto 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public StepType StepType { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PropertyLabel { get; protected set; }
    public Guid ProtocolId { get; set; }
    public List<SubStepDto> SubSteps { get; set; }
}



public class StartDateStepDto : StepBaseDto
{
    public DateTime? StartingDate { get; set; }
}



public class ProtocolDto : ProtocolBaseDto
{
    public List<StepBaseDto > StepSequence { get; set; }
}
```

Endpoint:

```
public override Task<ProtocolDto> GetAsync(Guid id)
```

When returning a ProtocolDto with its StepBaseDto list, I cannot see the properties of the derived classes on the **JSON** result.

But is working fine if I change

```
public class ProtocolDto : ProtocolBaseDto
{
    public List<object> StepSequence { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way I can accomplish the same result without changing StepBaseDto to object?

edit: I am using automapper

I found out a related question to this problem:
[Derived type's properties missing in JSON response from ASP.NET Core API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308763/derived-types-properties-missing-in-json-response-from-asp-net-core-api)

but the solution is not working for me, I am using ABP framework 5.3.4

[When using List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaiWu.png)

[When using List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q4fO.png)

**Fixed It by using dynamic instead of the base class**

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, why would you need to convert anything to object?

Comment: If I don't change the StepSequence List<StepBaseDto> to List<object> the Json result won't return the StartingDate property from StartDateStepDto. Thats the issue I am trying to resolve without changing StepBaseDto to object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Text.Json serialize derived class property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664086/system-text-json-serialize-derived-class-property)

Comment: uhmm will try, thanks to both of you!

Comment: Nothing is the question talked about JSON and then it pops up in the comments. Please make sure that the question is clear.

Comment: Do you need to deserialize, or only serialize?

Answer (score -1):

You can't see the subclass properties because you said it's a list of base classes. Any code that references that list will then also believe them to be the base classes. You can either:

1. Make the list a list of subclasses, or
2. Type cast every time you want to access those subclass properties, or
3. Move the subclass properties to an interface and use a list of interface, or
4. Move the subclass properties into the base class.

I think the trouble you're having is that you don't actually want a list of base classes if you are trying to access properties of the subclass. Since your subclass is only adding a nullable property, I would argue you could put that in the base class and not break anything - objects that don't have the property leave it null, ones that do can set the field.

It's not clear to me how you're trying to access this, how it's supposed to be used, etc., so it's hard to give you better guidance.

Comment: Isn't object the base class of every other class? I believe is an issue with the Json parser.

this is something related too also

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308763/derived-types-properties-missing-in-json-response-from-asp-net-core-api

Comment: @Mainumbi yes, object is the base class for every class, but you can't see the subclass properties in your list of object, either. Both object and your base class need to be cast to the subclass before you can access the properties, otherwise your code doesn't know they exist.

Answer (score -2):

Solution;
Microsoft.Text.Json <V6 doesn't support polymorphism, we must use
Newtonsoft Json parser. or you have to switch to V7 which is not possible for me.

full explanation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0

they force us to use object or just switch back to Newtonsoft

**Edit: a Good work around is to use dynamic instead of the base class**

Comment: Your answer here is all about JSON, but you didn't mention JSON *a single time* in the original question.

Comment: Hi I edited the post. This seems the corrent answer.

Comment: It might be the correct answer to what the question is now, but it's not the correct answer to the question that was originally asked.